# Is there a way to animate the icon of the ElevatedButton.icon() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I would like to animate the icon of this ElevatedButton when pressed.
The idea was to make the icon spin for a few seconds after pressing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwbOH.png) button.

Can anyone help me?

This is the code:

```dart
ElevatedButton.icon(
     onPressed: () {},
     icon: const Icon(Icons.sync),
     label: const Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
         child: Text("Sincronizza"),
     )
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AnimatedRotation` widget to do this easily!

### Code Sample

```dart
class SyncButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const SyncButton({
    super.key,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  @override
  State<SyncButton> createState() => _SyncButtonState();
}

class _SyncButtonState extends State<SyncButton> {
  double turns = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: widget.onPressed != null
          ? () {
              // Perform half rotation but you can increase the value
              setState(() => turns += 0.5);
              widget.onPressed?.call();
            }
          : null,
      icon: AnimatedRotation(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        turns: turns,
        child: const Icon(Icons.sync),
      ),
      label: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Text("Sincronizza"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=24796543b295dbaed3e2e130fd771a3f)

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you could do that in `ElevatedButton.icon` but, you could achieve it using `ElevatedButton` with some updates in the child.

Example:

```
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          /// animated this icon as you need OR You could use AnimatedIcon
                          Icon(Icons.sync),
                          Text('Sincronizza'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnimatedBuilder inside elevated button by passing as icon widget. Below I tried code when elevated button clicked the animation starts and will load until button is clicked again. you can control animated icon when to stop by making loader false and setstate it.

You can [preview or play with code here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5385f698d5eb426239a16c2d1a87ff76)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  
  late AnimationController _countroller;
  bool isLoading = false;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _countroller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds:1), vsync: this,)..repeat();
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
     onPressed: () {
       setState(() {
    isLoading = !isLoading;
  });
     },
     icon: isLoading ? AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _countroller,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child){
                return Transform.rotate(
                  angle: _countroller.value * 2.0 * math.pi,
                  child: const Icon(
                        Icons.sync,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                );
              }
            )
              : const Icon(
                        Icons.sync,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
     label: const Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
         child: Text("Sincronizza"),
     )
), 
      ),
    );
  }}
```